# Porque steam api recusa chamadas Angular?

Tags: angularjs, http, request

Eu estou simplesmente tentando alimentar minha aplicação com dados da api da Steam.
Vamos pegar este exemplo:  `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/?gameid=440&format=xml`

Cole no navegador e vai funcionar como devido.

Mas quando eu faço no `AngularJS` :

```
function getData(){
    return $http.get('aquela url')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
                })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);      
            });
}
```

Ele sempre cai no catch, com `statuscode:0` como se o servidor estivesse recusando ativamente meu request.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: No Chrome ou Firefox, o que a aba `Rede` das `Ferramentas de Desenvolvimento` dizem sobre a requisição? E o console?

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.` Sei que é problema de Cross Domain, mas como resolver sendo que não posso mexer na api da Steam? e outra que estou fazendo um `get`, e não um `post`

Comment: Não acho que seja possível. Os browsers implementam esta política por motivos de segurança. Driblá-la seria um problema de segurança.

Comment: Então a Steam faz uma api que não pode ser consumida. Isso não faz muito sentido

Comment: Agora que reparei, cadê sua API key? Sem ela, você não vai acessar.

Comment: Esta url nao exige apikey, tanto que se você colar no browser, vai funcionar. Para as outras chamadas eu tenho a devida apikey. Será que há outra forma, ou uma biblioteca "funcional" para acessar a api da steam? Estou testando SteamKit2 mas sem muito  sucesso

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver este problema tens que usar um servidor como "proxy".

Ou seja: Para este pedido funcionar, o mesmo tem que ser feito a partir de um servidor e não de um browser.
Dou um exemplo de PHP porque é o mais facil, no entanto este exemplo serve bem para perceberes o que fazer.
ps: já não escrevo php à uns tempos

```
if (!empty($_GET['steamCall'])) {
    echo file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/?gameid=440&format=xml');
}
```

Depois, no teu controlador em vez de chamares directamente a API da steam chamas o caminho do teu servidor com `?steamCall=true`. O teu servidor vai ao url da steam API e retorna para a tua aplicação o que a steamAPI respondeu à chamada do teu servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Vc deve ter um problema com cors (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Numa explicação bem resumida, quando vc tenta acessar alguma coisa com ajax fora do dominio de origem (Como é o caso do seu site acessando o steam) ele faz uma requisição anterior com método option pro endereço "perguntando" se sua aplicação pode fazer a requisição real.

Não conheço a api do steam, mas eles não devem ter habilitado o cors. 
Como o cors é um recurso do navegador (Implementado no navegador do cliente), requisições do seu servidor não são afetadas, ou seja, se vc fizer uma requisição com uma linguagem de programação qualquer partindo do seu servidor, o cors é ignorado.

Fazer uma requisição direta via angular não vai rolar a não ser que o steam habilite o cors. O que pode ser feito neste caso é usar alguma coisa no seu servidor para fazer um intercambio entre o angular e a api que vc quer acessar.

Existe proxys para cors feito em várias linguagens. Não sei qual é a que vc ta usando, mas se vc procurar no google cors proxy vc vai achar implementações em várias linguagens.